# Fill missing values of pandas based on values of other columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a following dataframe:

```
    A    B   C   D
0  NaN  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
3  NaN  3.0 NaN  4
```

Now I want to fill null values of A with the values in B or D. i.e. if the value is Null in B than check D. So resultant dataframe looks like this.

```
   A    B   C    D
0  2.0  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  5    NaN NaN  5
3  3.0  3.0 NaN  4
```

I can do this using following code:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df['B'])
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df['D'])
```

But I want to do this in one line, how can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply chain both `.fillna()`:

```
df['A'] = df.A.fillna(df.B).fillna(df.D)

    A    B   C   D
0  2.0  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  5.0  NaN NaN  5
3  3.0  3.0 NaN  4
```

---

Or using `fillna` with `combine_first`:

```
df['A'] = df.A.fillna(df.B.combine_first(df.D))
```

Answer (score 2):

If dont need chain because many columns better is use back filling missing values with seelcting first column by positions:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].fillna(df[['B','D']].bfill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0])
print (df)
     A    B   C  D
0  2.0  2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN  1
2  5.0  NaN NaN  5
3  3.0  3.0 NaN  4
```

Comment: What does zero specify in iloc?

Comment: It changes the value of A which was not null at first place. Like the second value in column A was 3 which was replaced by value 4 in B. But I want to fill just null values.